# How to keep bluetooth activity active

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth

In my application, I am using [Janos Gyerik's BluetoothViewer](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~janos-gyerik/bluetoothviewer/main/files) code to connect via Bluetooth.

I also have a `TCPServer` Class to connect via USB.

```
public void connectViaUSB() {
    if (GlobalVariables.connectionstatus == 0) {
        mTCPServer = new TCPServer(2222, getCurrentActivity());
        mTCPServer.start();
        mTCPServer.setResponseReceivedListener(this);
    }
```

The problem is, `BluetoothViewer` is written as an `Activity`. One needs to start the activity to connect, but when I switch to another activity connection is lost.

I need to either keep that activity up all the time, or find a way to modify it. How can I fix this situation?

**EDIT**

`
public class MyService extends Service {

```
private static final String TAG = "MyService";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    BluetoothAdapter mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mAdapter.enable();

    BluetoothChatService mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(mHandler);
    BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice("00:12:11:13:19:26");
    mChatService.connect(device);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //stop thread
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    //start thread (again)
}
```

}`

How can I make the Bluetooth connection from this Service Class? It requires me to move mHandler and I did. Now I'm getting RuntimeException: Unable to create .MyService: NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Service to connect to bluetooth. And when you will be needed use bluetooth just call service. This can help you: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: I am using a Service Class now, however I cannot initiate Bluetooth connection in there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this might help you but I created a robot once that was controlled by Bluetooth. It used a connection running inside a service/thread. For this I used the following 2 classes:

BluetoothSerialService.java

DeviceListActivity.java

Just google the 2 classes and you will find a place where they are hosted. Like here.
http://code.google.com/p/bluetooth-remote-control/source/browse/trunk/src/pro/apus/blueremote/?r=2

To actually setup the connection, just bind something like this to a button.

```
public void autoconnect() {

        t = new TextView(this);
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connecttext);
        mSerialService = new BluetoothSerialService(this, mHandlerBT, t);
        if (mSerialService.getState() == BluetoothSerialService.STATE_NONE) {
            BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
                    .getRemoteDevice(mMacAddress);
            mSerialService.connect(device);
        } else if (mSerialService.getState() == BluetoothSerialService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            mSerialService.stop();
            mSerialService.start();
        }
    }
```

And make sure to ask for permission before doing that.

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter
                .getDefaultAdapter();
        askBluetoothPermission(mBluetoothAdapter);
```